# Google Sheet convert horizontal data to vertical (not trasposing)

Tags: google-sheets

The raw data that I am receiving is oriented horizontally. I want to rearrange/convert the data to vertical to make data visualization easier.

Here is what I am getting
[Here is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VEdu.png)

Here is what want to end up having
[Here is what want to end up having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGjQP.png)

I was able to do it but was very crude and manual. I needed to manually fill up the columns for dates and name, then just have a Index-match formula to lookup what I need. However, it takes time and exposes me to error. Also doing it that way is not flexible if additional new statuses are created

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=let(date_,A2:A, name_,B2:B, type_,C1:E1, tot_,C2:E,
     Σ,reduce(wraprows(,4,),sequence(counta(date_)),lambda(a,c,{a;{wrapcols(index(date_,c),3,index(date_,c)),wrapcols(index(name_,c),3,index(name_,c)),tocol(type_),tocol(index(tot_,c))}})),
     filter(Σ,index(Σ,,1)<>""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
=LET(ll,A2:A,
      l,B2:B,
      u,C1:E1,
      r,C2:E,
      SORTN({TOCOL(IF(N(u)^0,ll)),
             TOCOL(IF(N(u)^0,l)),
             TOCOL(IF(N(l)^0,u)),TOCOL(r)},
        COUNT(IF(ll<>"",N(r)^0)),,1,1))
```

[image]